# PJSIP project not compiling with speex-aec enabled

Tags: pjsip, speex

I am using G.711 codec and aim to use Speex echo acoustic cancellation.

I tried to compile PJSIP project with the following command:

```
./configure --host=arm-unknown-none  --target=arm-unknown-none  --prefix=/home/iwahed/proj/embox/build/extbld/third_party/pjproject/core/install --disable-l16-codec --disable-ilbc-codec --disable-speex-codec --disable-gsm-codec --disable-g722-codec --disable-g7221-codec --disable-libyuv --disable-libwebrtc --disable-pjsua2 --enable-speex-aec && make dep && make
```

This results in the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/iwahed/proj/pjproject-2.11.1/pjmedia/lib/libpjmedia-arm-unknown-none.a(echo_common.o):(.data.rel+0x8): undefined reference to `speex_aec_create'
```

This function is defined in speex_echo.c.

Could I get some guidance what exactly is to be done to enable speex echo acoustic cancellation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable speex codec when using speex aec. Just remove
`--disable-speex-codec`

Comment: would I still be able to use G.711 as my codec or will I be forced to use speex codec?

Comment: You would still be able to use G711, just set the codec priority higher. Or to disable the speex codec by setting the priority to 0

Comment: Please vote for my question if you find it suitable